# Scroll event listener not working (vanilla javacscript)

Tags: javascript

```
let scrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
let about=document.querySelector('.aboutSec');

if(scrollPos > about.offsetTop){
    console.log('k');
}
```

I'm not getting any errors, but the console isn't logging anything either.
I can get the console to log the scrollPos if I do console.log(scrollPos), but my if statement isn't working. 
Also, I'm using chrome, I'm not sure if its a browser thing, but in videos I've seen somehow people get the console to auto update every time the page scrolls, for me, I have to scroll down to where I want the position number then refresh and it will give me the number.

Comment: I see no event listener. Did you add debug statement? `console.log(scrollPos, about.offsetTop);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this can help:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
  scrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if(scrollPos > about.offsetTop){
    console.log('k');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add event listener in javascript code

```
document.querySelector('.aboutSec').addEventListener('scroll', (e) => 
    {
      scrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
      if(scrollPos > about.offsetTop){
        console.log('k');
      }
    });
```

This will work.